# What gets executed when running a python app on OpenShift?

Tags: python, flask, initialization, openshift, server

I'm confused as to what file gets initially run when running a Flask application on OpenShift. There is a wsgi.py file that creates a wsgiref.simple_server but the comment above it says it is only for testing. Can anyone explain how the application get executed? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the process and where exactly the web server comes in to the picture vs the application code.

wsgi.py:

```
import os

virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR','.'), 'virtenv')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
#

from flaskapp import app



#
# Below for testing only
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    host = app.config['HOST_NAME']
    ip = app.config['HOST_IP']
    httpd = make_server(host, ip, app)
    httpd.handle_request()
```

flaskapp.py

```
import os

virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR','.'), 'virtenv')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
#

from flaskapp import app



#
# Below for testing only
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    host = app.config['HOST_NAME']
    ip = app.config['HOST_IP']
    httpd = make_server(host, ip, app)
    httpd.handle_request()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here from another SO question.

[How to create app using pyramid into openshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264103/how-to-create-app-using-pyramid-into-openshift/27324518?noredirect=1#comment44070557_27324518)

I think my last commit in my github example uses the "wsgi.py" entry point.  I prefer using "app.py" as the entry point. I find it is less problematic and more reliable.

Go ahead and rename "app.py disabled" to "app.py" and delete the wsgi.py.

I'm using pyramid instead of flask in the example but the setup is similar.